# Python - How do I create a new column in a dataframe from the unique values from an existing column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a data frame from an excel file.  I would like to create new columns from each unique value in the column 'animals'.  Can anyone help with this?  I am somewhat new to Python and Pandas.  Thanks.

In:

```
import pandas as pd

#INPUT FILE INFORMATION 
path = 'C:\Users\MY_COMPUTER\Desktop\Stack_Example.xlsx'
sheet = "Sheet1"

#READ FILE
dataframe = pd.io.excel.read_excel(path, sheet)
#SET DATE AS INDEX
dataframe = dataframe.set_index('date')
```

Comment: Can you show us the first rows of your dataframe. You can do that using dataframe.head()

Comment: 0 2015-02-10    dogs         1
1 2015-02-11    cats         2
2 2015-02-11    pigs         5
3 2015-02-13    dogs         3
4 2015-02-14    cats         5
5 2015-02-16    pigs         9
6 2015-02-16    dogs        10

Comment: Ardit, in this example, I would like for the new column 'dogs' to show '1' for the data 2015-02-10 (the columns 'cats' and 'pigs' would be '0')

Comment: This questions seems to be continued here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436975/python-how-to-create-new-columns-in-a-dataframe-from-the-unique-values-from-an/28437151#28436975 ...

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to create new columns from each unique value in the column "animals". As you did not specify what you want the new columns to have as values, I assume you want None values. 
So, here is the code:

```
for value in dataframe['animals']:
    if value not in dataframe:
        dataframe[value]=None
```

The first line loops through each value of the column 'animals'. 
The second line checks to make sure the value is not already in one of the columns so that your condition of having only unique values is satisfied. 
The third line creates new columns named under each unique value of column 'animals'.

Comment: Thank you.  And if I wanted to quantity of each animal to the new columns, how would I do that (rather than none)?